# Can a document have multiple Content Types?

Tags: content-type

My understanding is that a document can only have one Content Type yet I have several people telling me that it can.

Perhaps the confusion is around inheritance.  If I inherit from a parent Content Type like Contract and my child is Customer, would the child document be considered to be two content types, Contract and Customer?  If Contract has a workflow and Customer has a workflow, does Customer have two workflows associated with that content type?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No SP document or item can have only one content type. Child content types do not inherit the workflows so child content type will have only content types associated with it specifically. Maybe confusion comes from the fact that you can have multiple content types in same library.

Comment: Marek, just a follow up question... if the child doesn't inherit from the parent, what is the benefit of inheritance in Content Types?

Comment: it doesn't inherit the associated workflows, but it inherits the columns and when you change parent column setting (ie you add new one, or make one required) you can propagate that change to the child content types. For me the inheritance model makes sense for enterprise where they create base content type and the minimum required set of metadata to be recorded (ie for compliance reasons) then each dept inherits from it to create their own CTs with metadata that is relevant to them but not other depts but conforms to the baseline set by baseline ct.

Comment: Excellent!  Thanks!